# Filter records comparing fields from two different models in Odoo

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-12, odoo-13

I am creating a custom model in which users can introduce documents in Odoo. In my Document model I have a field security_level so, each document has an access level.
In the other hand I have included in res.users another field with the security level granted for each user.
The goal is that when a users try to access to documents, he will only be able to view documents with a document security level equal or below the user security level.

My document model:

```
class Documents(models.Model):
_name = 'custom_documents.document'
_description = 'Document'

document_id = fields.Integer()
name = fields.Char()
state = fields.Selection([('draft', 'Draft'), ('approved', 'Approved'), ('rejected', 'Rejected')], default="draft")
security_level = fields.Selection([('10', 'Employee'), ('20', 'Manager'), ('99', 'Administrator')], default="10")
partner_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner')
project_id = fields.Many2one('project.task', string="Project")
user_id = fields.Many2one('hr.employee', string='Employee')
document = fields.Binary()
category = fields.Many2one('custom_documents.category')
subcategory = fields.Many2one('custom_documents.subcategory')
```

In res.users:

```
class ResUsers(models.Model):
_inherit = 'res.users'

security_docs = fields.Selection([('10', 'Employee'), ('20', 'Manager'), ('99', 'Administrator')], default="10")
```

But I don't know how to compare security_docs and security_level from Documents and res.users, and how to grant access to the current users if his security level is higher than the document one.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I have no time to give you a full answer right now, but i can give you a hint: look into the model `ir.rule` and some examples Odoo is using already.

Comment: I have already try with record rules, but I didn't manage to make it work

Comment: The domain should be fairly easy: `[('security_level', '<=', user.security_level)]` and the rule should be for model `custom_documents.document`.

Comment: The only problem is that I can not use <, odoo considers it as a an open tag

Comment: use `&lt;` instead